# How can I stretch everything in my window when window is maximized in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, screen, maximize

I have got my main wingow with ribbon tabs and a datagrid. How can I maximize everythin in the window when window is maximized to fit the screen?I am trying to use viewbox but its not working.

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                <ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon">

                    <ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="HomeTab" 
                                  Header="Home">
                        <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="Group1" 
                                        Header="Refresh">
                            <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="BtmRefresh"
                                             LargeImageSource="Images\refresh.png"
                                             Label="Refresh" Margin="25,0,30,0" Click="BtmRefresh_Click" />
                        </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
                    </ribbon:RibbonTab>
                </ribbon:Ribbon>


            <StackPanel Name="PanelDataGrid" Height="Auto" >

                    <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,138,0,0" Name="dataGrid" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  SelectionUnit="Cell"   AlternatingRowBackground="#FFDFE9F5"
                 SelectionMode="Single" ColumnWidth="68"  HeadersVisibility="Column" RowBackground="{x:Null}" >
                        <DataGrid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/GridCellColor;component/Images/barcode.png" />
                        </DataGrid.Background>
                        <DataGrid.Columns >

                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Job_Num}"  Header="Job Nº" IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Product_Code}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Product" Width="1*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                 </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

And I tried adding  before grid tag

Help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I would suggest posting a sample of your xaml code to get a better and more specific answer

Comment: Can you post your XAML code with the ViewBox?

Comment: @Rachel Pls have a look to my code with the question it has been edited.

Comment: @Rachel and @msarchet when I add Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="5,5,5,5" It is stretching everything However my columns dissapear and I just have my 1st column on my grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `StretchDirection="Both"` to your ViewBox and it should work

```
// Will Stretch it and keep the ratio the same
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both">


// Will Stretch it to fill full screen regardless of ratio
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both">
```

Comment: yeah is stretching but want font to get bigger and the entire grid and tab to get bigger so If I project this in bigger screen looks bigger. I hope you are understanding what i am saying.How can I do that. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Not working when I try to do that my all window get condensed in a line.

Comment: I have got my problem solved, was because on my DataGridTextColumn I had Widht "1*" changed to fixed one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to go out and guess that you need to anchor your viewbox to the sides of the control. This is the margin property.

Your `ViewBox` should have something that looks like `Margin=5,5,5,5` in it's XAML.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you are saying

Comment: @Rachel and @msarchet when I add Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="5,5,5,5" It is stretching everything However my columns dissapear and I just have my 1st column on my grid.